# Make sql server script folder name dynamic

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

I have been trying to execute SQL scripts from a folder which contains number of sql scripts. These scripts will create a complete database so I want to execute scripts in a sequence and so I wrote this code and placed that in a script.

```
:r c:\Scripts\CREATE_TABLE1.sql -- sql file to create first table
:r c:\Scripts\CREATE_TABLE2.sql -- sql file to create second table 
:r c:\Scripts\CREATE_TABLE3.sql -- sql file to create third table
```

Its working fine and I just need to make the folder name dynamic so that we can change folder name easily by creating a variable at top and use it with every filename. I explored some options but didn't find much and ended up something like this. But this doesn't work.

```
Declare @FolderName varchar(100)
set @FolderName='C:\Scripts\'
:r @FolderName+'CREATE_TABLE1.sql -- create first table
:r @FolderName+'CREATE_TABLE2.sql -- create second table
:r @FolderName+'CREATE_TABLE3.sql -- create third table
```

but it throws error that incorrect syntax near first r command after folder name. Someone please tell me how do I fix it or some work around?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setvar` & `$()`;

```
:setvar FolderName "C:\Scripts"
:r $(FolderName)\CREATE_TABLE1.sql'
:r $(FolderName)\.....
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. it says Incorrect syntax near :setvar (first line). Any idea? This is how I am using it. :setvar FileToexecute "CREATE1.sql" :setvar workpath "c:\Scripts\" :r $(workpath)$(FileToExecute)

Comment: It works for me in management studio's sqlcmd mode, there is also sqlcmd-v; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188714.aspx

Comment: It sure works in sqlcmd mode. I guess I will need to change my approach a little[using SQLCMD]. Thanks for help Alex